# Retrieve an image from SharePoint Online in iOS

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, apple-ios

Does anyone know how to retrieve an image from SharePoint Online - Office 365 into an iOS app?

The image logo has the following returned format: https://"TENANT".sharepoint.com/"SITE NAME"/SiteAssets/domain1.png

I've implemented a custom Web API to retrieve the site collections. A specific site might have a logo and from my iOS app I could get its url after calling the service.

The problem is that I receive 401 or 403 for getting the image no matter if I pass or not the obtained token for the Web Api call as an authorisation header.

```
SDWebImageDownloader *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
[manager setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


[logo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:site.logo] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 401.)"
```

Also my logs contains the following info:
*Access denied. Before opening files in this location.*

Comment: Is "Display images" option in safari enabled?